# Scripting the input device

Tags: input-devices

On macOS I currently use [hammerspoon](https://www.hammerspoon.org/) to script all kinds of automations. It offers APIs to the clipboard buffer, window placement, and many more (c.f. the [API doc](https://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/index.html)).

Most importantly, it offers the possibility to handle keyboard input, which I use to create systemwide modal layers for the keyboard (c.f. [example config](https://github.com/jasonrudolph/keyboard)).

As I consider switching to Ubuntu, I wonder if there is an easy way to hook into the input devices, in order to create my own system-wide modal keyboard layout.

An added bonus would be a set of APIs resembling the ones of hammerspoon for Linux and Gnome.